# point error in BST's delete function

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
Delete(key, T){
    BstTree TmpCell; //one tree node
    if(T == NULL)
        return Not Found;
    else if(key < T->data)
        T->LeftChild = Delete(key, T->LeftChild);
    else if(key > T->data)
        T->RightChild = Delete(key, T->RightChild);
    else if(T->LeftChild&& T->RightChild){
        TmpCell = Findmin(T->RightChild);
        T->data = TmpCell->data;
        T->RightChild = Delete(T->data, T->RightChild);
    }
    else{
        TmpCell = T;
        if(T->LeftChild = NULL) T= T->RightChild; 
        if(T->RightChild = NULL) T=T->LeftChild;
        free(TmpCell); 
    }
    return T; 
}
```

[image: BSTTREE]

I found the code in 《data structures and algorithm analysis in C》.

If I want to delete 14

```
 else{
        TmpCell = T;
        if(T->LeftChild = NULL) T = T->RightChild; 
        if(T->RightChild = NULL) T =T->LeftChild;
        free(TmpCell); 
     }
```

After I find 14, T (14) moves to T's LeftChild (13), but TmpCell is still pointing to 14, and then I free it. But when I output the Tree, it outputs 13, so how did 13 get connected to 14's parent?

Comment: You have to maintain parent of `T` also.So that you can do something like `T_parent->left = T->child`

Comment: I don't understand the question. After deleting 14, it can still output 13. What's the problem?

Comment: I free the point 14, and I don't connect point 13 to 14's parent,  but when I traverse the tree, 13 can be output ,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "connecting" part happens when `Delete`'s return value is assigned to something, i.e. in the lines

```
        T->LeftChild = Delete(key, T->LeftChild);
```

and

```
        T->RightChild = Delete(key, T->RightChild);
```

in the function itself, and at its caller:

```
myTree = Delete(x, myTree);
```

(that's how you're supposed to call it).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I understand it.